# Unnecessary conditional cast (compiler's warning) required for let binding to succeed

Tags: ios, swift3

I am having a weird behavior with a conditional cast, there is no problem for the app to work but I am trying to understand why this is happening. The issue is when I try to pass a tuple in the `sender:` parameter of `performSegue`.

I have a `Navigation Controller` as my `Storyboard Entry Point`. There are some cases when I unwind to my `root view controller` then I perform a `segue` programmatically from my `Navigation Controller`, this would look something like this:

```
@IBAction func unwindSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.navigationController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "someSegue",
            sender: ("Hello", "World"))
    }
}
```

Now, in my `Navigation Controller` I expect the `segue` like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "someSegue" {
        if let someViewController = segue.destination as? SomeViewController,
            let tuple = sender as? (String,String) {
            someViewController.navigationItem.title = tuple.0 + " " + tuple.1
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that this doesn't work, I have to make a conditional cast in my `unwindSegue` like this:

```
self.navigationController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "someSegue",
    sender: ("Hello", "World") as? (String,String))
```

Of course the compiler throws warnings at this:

`Conditional cast from '(String, String)' to '(String, String)' always succeeds`

Why is this happening? Shouldn't the let binding in my `prepare(for segue:,sender:)` suffice? Why should I cast it in my `unwindSegue(segue:)` if sender will arrive as `Any?` no matter what.

Comment: I'm wondering the exact same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40558360/perform-segue-and-send-tuple-as-sender

Comment: I was able to avoid the warnings with this: `self.navigationController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "someSegue", sender: ("Hello", "World") as Any)`.
I still don't get the issue, as soon as I understand the `Any` type from the Apple documentation I will try to post an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you have to make a cast is because the sender is an Any? and this implicates that you don't know what you are receiving. It can be anything or nil. You do, however, send a tuple of two strings, that you don't necessarily need to cast.

The question is whether you are unwinding in the right way. Normally the sender is an object that gives information on the sender unwinding the previous view controller. This, of course, can be a tuple of two strings, but the prepare for segue does expect something else.

Hope this gives you some info on the topic.

Comment: Yes indeed, that's why I am wondering, shouldn't the let binding suffice in my `prepare(for segue:,sender:)`? Even if I make the cast in my `unwindSegue(segue:)` the tuple will arrive as `Any?` in my `prepare(for segue:,sender:)` isn't that right? By the way this is just a simple example with `(String,String)`, in my actual example I am using a tuple of custom objects but the behavior is the same