# perform segue and send tuple as sender

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I've been trying to set a tuple to the sender object when doing a perform segue like:

`performSegue(withIdentifier: "", sender: ("hello", "hello2"))`

But inside `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` I'm getting cast exception when trying to cast sender as `(String, String)`

It seems that only the first element of the tuple is in `sender`.

I'd expect since sender is of type `Any?` I could use a tuple as variable?

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621413-performsegue), the sender is supposed to be the object that is initiating the segue; this is not a place for you to stuff data to pass to the destination viewcontroller.  Instead you should put it in a property in your view controller and then use it to set the destination view controller's properties in prepareForSegue.

Anyways, to answer your question, here is how you cast back from Any? to a tuple of (String, String)

```
let b = ("g", "f")
let a: Any? = b
if let c = a as? (String, String) {
    print (c)
}
```

Comment: I've seen several examples where people are using sender to pass data. Anyhow that's another discussion. Just wondering why the sender I receive in prepareForSegue is not my original tuple. Try it for yourself.

Comment: There is no problem with using `sender` to pass data, but there is rarely a good reason to use tuples. Use a struct or an object

Comment: @Paulw11 why no reason to use a tuple? Tuple is of type Any right? I'm wondering because maybe apple's API of performSegue and prepareForSegue needs to be updated.

Comment: Because tuples don't have formal types or parameter names; they are unstructured. Your code will be more reliable if your types have structure

Comment: Tuples can have parameter names, they're just optional. Anyway this is also not what my original post is about. It's why I can't can't cast my tuple from sender.

Comment: You are correct that it doesn't work if you pass a tuple as sender.  Note that my example does work and so the answer must be that passing a tuple as Any to Objective C seems to just get you the first element.  This makes sense because Any becomes id and Objective C has no notion of Swift Tuples.  Anyways I reiterate the documentation says this is supposed to be the sending object and not the data.  I would not use this for data in a real program because its going to annoy and confuse the people you work with.

Answer (score 2):

Even if the argument sender is not supposed to be used to pass any data or it may not be a good practice, I find it useful and clean. I don't think it would confuse people of a working team if its short and simple. I think Apple's API some way gets it the way Obj-C treats it.

I've tried some ways to pass it and find a way I'd use:

In array:

```
    let tuple = ("string1", "string2")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "theSegue", sender: [tuple])
```

So you get:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let data = sender as? [Any] {
        if let first = data.first {
            print(first)
        }
    }
}
```

Or as a dictionary:

```
    let tuple = ("string1", "string2")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "theSegue", sender: ["userInfo":tuple])
```

So you get:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let data = sender as? [String:Any] {
        if let userInfo = data["userInfo"] {
            print(userInfo)
        }
    }
}
```